# Single word request to describe if a train is "departing from" or "arriving at" a specific station

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to describe whether a train is "departing from" or "arriving at" a specific station.

For example,

> Q: Excuse me. Do you know the [***] of (or between) train T01 and station S02? (asking if the train T01 is departing from or arriving at the station S02)

> A: Yes, The train is arriving at station S02.

What is the word [***] that most describes such situation?

Single word is preferred.

Comment: I assume this is a field in a database of some sort? If so, it's likely off-topic for ELU.

Comment: @alphabet Thank you for the warning. I have edited the question so that it is likely on-topic now.

Comment: The issue, of course, is that typically any train at any station will both arrive at and later depart from it.

Comment: @alphabet Ok. So, I will add a new information, which is the station related to the train. Therefore, it will boil down to whether the train "depart from" or "arrive at" the specific station.

Comment: Colloquially I might ask "Is that train coming or going?" if I'm not sure if it's getting ready for departure or has just pulled in and is staying there.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking for a reasonably narrowly defined single word hypernym (Wiktionary includes phrases as hypernyms) for ['arrival' and 'departure']. I think you'll only find unhelpfully broad ones. 'Comings and goings' is a fairly informal idiomatic phrase.

Comment: "Direction" might help in some cases

Comment: Would _schedule_ do?

Comment: @Henry : more precisely "direction of travel".

Comment: Every train that arrives must also depart. Are you asking about a time schedule? (“Is 9:05 the arrival time or the departure time for train T1 at station S2?”)

Answer (score 1):

A broader word including arrivals and departures would be *movements*. This would include movements to or from a siding as well as movements that are involved in a journey.

Answer (score 1):

"Do you know if T01 will be inbound at S02?"

If it's not inbound (arriving) then it will be outbound (departing).